# Center window horizontally and vertically

Tags: kde, kwin

Is there a setting in "Global Keyboard shortcuts" to center a floating window vertically and horizontally on the current desktop?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a default keyboard shortcut to center windows. (See the comment by mgraesslin in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/7h6g8e/move_window_to_center_patch/) for why not!)

A convenient way to see what's available, by default, is to look at the`[kwin]` section in your `~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc`.

However, if you want windows to be centered when they're *initially opened*, navigate to *System Settings > Window Management > Window Behavior > Window Actions and Behavior*. In there, click on the *Advanced* tab and then make your choice from the dropdown that appears when you click on *Placement*.

If you want an existing window currently *not* centered to be centered by using a keyboard shortcut, look at the available [Kwin Scripts](https://store.kde.org/browse/cat/210/order/latest/) compatible with *your* version of software.

*Move Window to Center* is one such script:

> A simple KWin script that introduces a KDE Global Shortcut (Meta+C by default) for centering the active window in the current screen.

To install this script in Kubuntu 18.04<sup>***</sup>:

---

*Before installing this script*, please ensure that <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> has not already been assigned to something else. This script requires that <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> be available as the keyboard shortcut.

---

- Open *System Settings > Window Management > KWin Scripts*.
- Click on *Get New Scripts …*.
- A new window opens. Enter "center" in the search box.
- Look for *Move Window to Center* by *artemisfowl2007* and click on *Install*. Once the installation is done, you can close the window.
- Reboot. Pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> should now move the active window to the center of your screen without altering its dimensions.

<sup>***</sup>This script also works in Kubuntu 19.10 (with Plasma 5.18.3) or in Kubuntu 20.04 (scheduled for release in April 2020).

Comment: Instead of reboot, you can just press `Alt+F2` and run command  `kwin_x11 --replace`.